# Indexed search using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a huge list in memory, about 1.000.000 elements.

I need to search if a specific item exists in this list using linq, but it looks to be so slow, because I have to do this a thousand times.

```
    private bool FindElement(int property1, int property2)
    {
        return myList.Where(x => x.foo == property1
            && x.bar == property2).Any();
    }
```

Is there a way to index that search?

Comment: Directly use `myList.Any(x => x.foo == ...)`. This will short-circuit when a match is found.

Comment: @adiga `Where` is lazy-evaluated, so shortcut will be here anyway, but it's still can give better performance

Comment: Use Skip and Take.

Comment: "I have to do this thousand times". Maybe that's where you need to change things. What's the reason to do this that many times?

Comment: If you have 1M items, why don't you use a database? LINQ has nothing to do with indexing, it's just a query language. Indexing is something done by the underlying provider. When you use LINQ to Objects, there's no indexing involved, just `IEnumerable` operations. You need to use a different container, like a Dictionary or HashSet.

Comment: @JL0PD being lazy-evaluated has nothing to do with the shortcut behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it could be a possible solution to change management from a List to dictionary.

The read phase in a List is a potential O(n).
Dictionaries because they handle data in an indexed way are a potential O(1).

If you can use the dictionary in my opinion you get a decent speed increase.

A possible solution with dictionary, could be to use property concatenation as a key or id. Not knowing the structure of the objects it is difficult to give an example of implementation... however a naïve solution could be:

```
Dictionary<string, YourClassType> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, YourClassType>();
dictionary.Add("" + property1 + property2, YourClassObject);

string key = "" + property1 + property2;
if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{
   Console.WriteLine("For key = \"tif\", value = {0}.", value);
}
```

Even if you need to use a list for other reasons, you can build the dictionary once ahead of any searching, but keep the list.

Comment: You use "123" key for 12+3 properties and for 1+23 too. You could use numbers directly, no need for conversion into strings.

Comment: good point, it's an example and i don't know the type of the property. If the type are int you are right.

Comment: I'd use value tuples `(propert1, property2)` as keys.

Comment: @GertArnold i think it's a best solution

Answer (score -3):

You can implement your own `Any` that will perform faster than linq-based implementation

```cs
public static bool Any<T>(this IList<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    if (collection is T[] ar)  // type check to avoid virtual calls
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ar.Length; i++)
        {
             if (predicate(ar[i]))
             {
                  return true;
             }
        }
        return false;
    }
    if (collection is List<T> lis) // this one to avoid virtual calls too
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lis.Count; i++)
        {
             if (predicate(lis[i]))
             {
                  return true;
             }
        }
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < collection.Count; i++) // it's different kind of IList
    {
         if (predicate(collection[i]))
         {
              return true;
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you assume this is any faster than LINQ? You're still iterating over everything

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos iterating over array or list is faster with indexer than with enumerator

Comment: Better written loop can be like 1.5x faster? Maybe 2x times? Better time complexity approach can be like 100000x faster. That is the fruit worth picking.